# getting "bad init string" when dialing with wvdial

Tags: configuration, modem, gsm, wvdial

I'm trying to dial-up with my Huawei modem EM680 using wvdial.
My modem is found properly on `/dev/ttyUSB1` but when I execute wvdial I get this:

```
# wvdial
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","m2mstatic.apn"
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","m2mstatic.apn"
ERROR
--> Bad init string.
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","m2mstatic.apn"
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","m2mstatic.apn"
ERROR
--> Bad init string.
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","m2mstatic.apn"
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","m2mstatic.apn"
ERROR
--> Bad init string.
#
```

Why does it say `bad init string.`?
My `/etc/wvdial.conf` looks like this:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","m2mstatic.apn"
Stupid Mode = yes
Modem Type = Analog Modem
ISDN = 0
New PPPD = yes
Phone = *99#
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB1
Username = ;
Password = ;
Baud = 9600
```

Comment: That error is because your modem rejected the Init3 string:

    `--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","m2mstatic.apn"
    AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","m2mstatic.apn"`
    `ERROR`

That string came straight from the `Init3` setting in your config file. Unfortunately, I have no experience with that hardware, or anything similar, so I can't really provide an answer... I can suggest https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto/Huawei/E220 might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This wvdial.conf worked on ZTE 3G Modem below:

```
[Dialer Defaults] 
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0 
Init1 = ATZ 
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","apnname" 
Phone = *99***1#
Username = user
Password = user
New PPPD = yes 
Stupid Mode = 1
```

You can try it with my wvdial.conf.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem, then found that I did not have a SIM card in the device.
When I added the SIM card, it worked again.

Perhaps the SIM card is locked?
I have seen other postings that have suggested adding:

```
AT+CPIN="0000"
```

to the script (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto/Huawei/E220)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My sim card was old, but when I replaced  it with a new one and also tightened all the screws on the modem, it fixed the problem.